# Hover for Java Editor

Tags: eclipse, plugins, hover

How to write a hover for only some elements in the Java Editor displaying the information of that element like creation time and element owner while retaining the default hovers for elements like Class and Methods.

I am new to plugin environment. Please assist me with code snippets

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers` extension point to do Java editor text hovers, for example this is the hover used for the debug hover:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers">
  <hover
        label="%javaVariableHoverLabel"
        description="%javaVariableHoverDescription"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDebugHover"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDebugHover">
  </hover>
</extension>
```

See the [help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaEditorTextHovers.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much..But I need to add extra information to the JavaElements along with the default information. how can I do that.It will be great, if anyone explains me by implementing the  IJavaEditorTextHover.